# How to create UI for Spark AR?

Tags: user-interface, spark-ar-studio

I'm new to Spark AR and I'm having issues creating a UI that sticks to the screen rather than moving with the 3D object (I'm using plane tracking). Does anyone have a tutorial you followed or could tell me how to do it?

My end game is to have the user be able to switch between 3D models by touching two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a canvas object?

See here:
https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/tutorials/2D-objects-and-layers